Spyder ctrl+i, ctrl+click, "go to definition" not working
After installing standalone python, and Spyder from the installer, I can't appear to view docstrings, or use some helpful features such as ctrl+click/"go to definition" for modules I'm using. They do not return any error code, they just don't do anything.
I'm using the latest version of python (3.13), and spyder (6.02)

This appears to occur when pointing spyder at the standalone python kernel you have installed rather than the default. Try installing spyder from pip in the python version you desire, following the official instructions here: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/installation.html
This will require first installing Visual Studio Build tools ( https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022 )
and Rust (https://rustup.rs/)
After which one can attempt installation with pip install spyder, and finally running the program with spyder
